# How to restore a database from a .bak file?

Tags: sql-server, restore

My `.bak` file is the other the local server.

I tried too many different script but unable to successes.

I tried syntax is

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='D:\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'
```

Get the Logicalname from above query and use in below query

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test FROM DISK='ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test.mdf',
   MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta_log' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test_log.ldf',
   REPLACE,
STATS=10
```

After executing above query below error is generate.

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Please help me for this manner

Comment: .bak file is in the local machine

Comment: What about reading the message? `Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)`

Comment: this is the error message which is return from the sql server

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have backed up a db on one server, and you want to restore it to another server.  Is this correct?

Your backup file `D:\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak` is on server A, right?  It needs to be accessible to the account running the SQL Server service on server B.  A few quick options come to mind:

1. Create a share on server A, move the backup file into the corresponding shared folder.
2. Move the backup file to an existing UNC path.
3. Move the backup file to server B.

Then proceed with the restore.  If you chose option 1 or 2, it will be something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test 
FROM DISK='\\SomeServer\Shared Folder\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'
WITH 
    MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test.mdf',
    MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta_log' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test_log.ldf',
REPLACE,
STATS=10
```

If you chose option 3, it will look something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test 
FROM DISK='D:\Path on Server B\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'
WITH 
    MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test.mdf',
    MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta_log' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test_log.ldf',
REPLACE,
STATS=10
```

Comment: Yes "It sounds like you have backed up a db on one server, and you want to restore it to another server."
But my backup file is in local server which I want to restore it.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas: Ok, so your backup file is in local server.  Got it.
Do you want to restore the backup file to the same local server?

Comment: yes do you face this type of issue ?if yes so please help me

Comment: PragneshKhalas:  @marc_s has already answered your question.  And now, in a roundabout way, I have answered it too.  I don't think there's anything more I can do to help you.  All the information you need is here.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: From SqlServer management studio there's an option to restore a database from the UI. It allows you to browse to find the source bak file. The browse window opened is on the **database server machine** NOT the machine where you are running management studio.

Answer (score 1):

You're only specifying a "relative" path for the `.bak` file here:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test FROM DISK='ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'
```

and quite obviously, from the error message, the file isn't there where this points to.

> *Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'. Operating system error 2 (The system **cannot find** the file specified.)*

You'll need to specify the **full, complete path** to the `.bak` file here:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test FROM DISK='D:\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak'
                                *****
```

If you would **actually try and specify the complete path here** so that SQL Server can find it's source for the restore - I'm always positive it'll work......

Comment: Actually error is not for the .bak file. It is error for the logical file like .mdf and .ldf is unable to find in local machine because .bak file other the the local server so when we call MOVE 'ERPAgrotechBeta' TO 'D:\Pragnesh\Test.mdf' at that time engine try to find source .mdf file and it is unable to find.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas: if you **READ** the error - it's very **CLEAR** that the  `.bak` file **isn't found**!!

Comment: Yes but .bak file is exist in D:\ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak and I tried to restore this .bak file in one of the Test database which is in the local server.

Comment: I would upvote this but I do not want to create an incentive to answer such questions. Your answer is not being appreciated.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas: in the case - **you need to specify the FULL PATH** (`*D:\*ERPNewtesting-12022014.bak`) to the `.bak` file! Try it!!

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup is not exist path in the local server

Comment: The error also said that the file cannot be OPENED.

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly due to the rights issue :-

Follow below 2 steps and it will resolve :-

1. Let the Server take backup on default directory and copy the file in your desired folder. I did that.
2. Give same kind of permissions to your desired folder as Backup directory has.

OR

U can add the service account into local admin group of the machine where backup is taken