# Unable to restore SQL Server .bak file

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have a SQL Server .bak file. Under the properties, it says "Opens with Notepad". When I try to restore from the .bak file where it says "Opens with Notepad", I get the following error "Cannot open backup device. 'L:...' Operating System error 2 (the system cannot find the file specified)". But when I restore from a clear .BAK file saying noting about 'opens with notepad', the restore process works fine. How can I restore such files? (everything is on the same server and I've SQL Server 2012 standard edition). See the attached screenshot.
[BakFile Screenshot][[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1XUW.png

Comment: What is a 'clear' .bak file?

Comment: How are you trying to restore ? Windows does not differentiate between different .bak files so not sure what you are trying to do here . SQL Server backup files are not recommended to be opened with notepad , as doing so might cause corruption of the file

Comment: See the attached screenshots above.

Comment: Show file extension, then probably you'll know what's your problem.

Comment: The file extension is "File" for the first one (which can be restored without issues) and "BAK File" for the second one (where I'm unable to restore).

Comment: What application are you using to do the restore?  It looks like you are using Windows Explorer.  Are you using SQL Server Management Studio, which is what you should be using...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the `.bak` extension on the backup dated 7/9/2018, but remembered to add the `.bak` extension on the backup dated 5/27.  SQL Server does not automatically add `.bak` to a backup file.  If you forget to add it, the backup file looks like yours dated 7/9/2018.

Someone double-clicked a `.bak` file at one time and Windows asked the user how they wanted to open it.  They selected Notepad.  Windows associated the `.bak` file extension with Notepad so that it always uses Notepad when you double-click a `.bak` file (or when you right-click it, you see a `Open with Notepad` because `.bak` is associated with Notepad).

You cannot easily remove the association between `.bak` and Notepad because Microsoft removed the ability from the GUI to delete a file type association after Windows XP.  Here are a couple of links that explains how to do it via the `Command Prompt`:

- https://superuser.com/questions/159927/how-to-delete-a-file-association
- https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7

When you restore a database, you should **not** double-click or right-click the backup file from Windows Explorer.  Instead, you should use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  Right-click the database from the `Object Explorer` and select `Tasks | Restore | Database`, and then follow the wizard.  Or, if you want to restore it to a new database, right-click the object called `Databases` and then select `Restore Database`, then follow the wizard.

The reason SQL Server cannot access the file could be due to many different reasons.  Here is a link for another user who asked for help with the same error: [How to restore a database from a .bak file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858008/how-to-restore-a-database-from-a-bak-file)

Have you tried to copy the file to a local drive (instead of restoring from a network mapped drive `L:`)?  You may have better luck restoring from `C:`...